# javascript- How can detach specific element by mouseposition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have project to build designer but I have small problem to detach the specific element if the mouse went to one rectangle. I need to know which of the rectangle

html is similar to this [https://jsfiddle.net/abdulaziz_IS1995/YjC6y/3820/](https://jsfiddle.net/abdulaziz_IS1995/YjC6y/3799/)

My code for drag and drop !!

- **element parameter** : means the selectedElement from html .
- **closestDiv** : means the closest Parent to the selected  element .

```js
   function trackArea(element, closestDiv) {
   var x = closestDiv.position().top;
        var y = closestDiv.position().left;
        if (element.getBoundingClientRect().top >= x && element.getBoundingClientRect().left >= y) {
            $(closestDiv).droppable({ tolerance:closestDiv});
            $(element).draggable({
                containment: closestDiv[0],
                cancel: '',
                appendTo: closestDiv[1],
                accept:element, 
                option: ''
            }, true); 
            $(element).sortable({
                change: function (event, ui) {
                    var currentClass = $(ui.placeholder)[0].classList[0];
                    if (!$(ui.placeholder).prev().hasClass(currentClass) && !$(ui.placeholder).next().hasClass(currentClass))
                        return false;
                    }
            });
            $(element).disableSelection();
            element.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e1) {
                isDown = true;
                offset = [
                    closestDiv.offsetLeft - e1.clientX,
                    closestDiv.offsetTop - e1.clientY
                ];
            }, true);
            element.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
                isDown = false;
            }, true);
            element.addEventListener('onmousemove', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if (isDown) {
                    mousePosition = {
                        x: event.clientX,
                        y: event.clientY
                    };
                    element.style.left = (mousePosition.x + closestDiv.offset[0]) + 'px';
                    element.style.top = (mousePosition.y + closestDiv.offset[1]) + 'px';
                }
            }, true);
            if ($(element).parent('DIV')[0].id === closestDiv[0].id) {
                closestDiv[0].addEventListener('mousedown', function () { this.setAttribute("draggable", false);});
                closestDiv[0].addEventListener('mouseup', function () { this.setAttribute("draggable", false); });
            }
        } else if (element.getBoundingClientRect().top <=x   && element.getBoundingClientRect().left >= y ) {
            element.addEventListener('mousemove', function () {
                mousePosition = {
                    x: event.clientX,
                    y: event.clientY
                };
                element.style.left = (mousePosition.x + offset[0]) + 'px';
                element.style.top = (mousePosition.y + offset[1]) + 'px';
            } , false ); 
        }
```

Comment: Your snippet is not woring

Comment: You've skipped } sign in the end of your code

Comment: i don't have the html because the html is too big sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Simple by CSS you can do it

```
yourHTMLElement {pointer-events: none;}
```

Comment: i don't think this is will solve the problem , my issues was to detch where my mouse is after i chose the element to drag on and what is the position i drop it

Answer (score 0):

i used some function called 'elementFromPoint' i put the coordinate of the mouse  and then still return to me the main Div 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX4Az.png)

i added on my code this

```js
 element.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e1) {
                isDown = true;
                offset = [
                    closestDiv.offsetLeft - e1.clientX,
                    closestDiv.offsetTop - e1.clientY
                ];
                ele = document.elementFromPoint(e1.clientX, e1.clientY); 
                if (ele.parentElement.id !== org.id) {
                    alert(ele.parentElement.id); 

                }
            }, true);
```